# How to retrieve the ID of the sent e-mail via GmailApp?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs-api, google-drive-api, gmail-api

Here is a sample code

```
GmailApp.sendEmail("email@example.com", "mail subject", "mail body");
```

after the call I can see a sent message in my gmail account and that has a ID like this `147f7e77a4efed11` I want to retrieve this ID for the sent mail via the above code

sendEmail method returns an instance of `GmailApp` which is useful for chaining actions but no way to get the ID of the sent email.

what I am doing now is to perform a search and take the first message. But I am sure that is not a reliable way.

example

```
var message = GmailApp.search("to:email@example.com", 0, 1)[0].getMessages()[0];
```

now I can get the ID of the message and perform the desired actions.

Is it possible to retrieve the message or the ID of the message without an unreliable search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After building your service, you can use the `messages.list` and then filter them like you would when searching in GMail, you can also use [labels](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) to get only sent mails etc.

```
messages = gmail_service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q="subject:mail subject deliveredto:email@example.com", maxResults=1).execute()
if messages['messages']:
    for message in messages['messages']:
        print 'message ID: %s' % (message['id'])
```

If you pass through the email you're searching for and other "unique" references as arguments in a Python function it makes it a lot more versatile too.

**Edit:** After talking with you I think that creating your own personal ID/reference for each email sent would be the most prudent method of retrieval. I recommend using [faker](https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/), they have a javascript version and I use faker for all of my data needs. There's plenty of documentation for it and then you can filter your list according to how you set your ID.

Comment: thank you for the effort, but this approach will also face the same issue like the search. the problem with the approach is that you can not trust the results. this piece of code is supposed to run in multi-user environment and there are high chances that this approach may return the same message from two simultaneous calls while missing one of them.

Comment: this code is used in a mailing service, it is based on triggers from multiple users. so multiple sessions of the services are invoked on the same account/inbox.

Comment: Adding a custom ID! Thank you Stormie, may you add the same in the answer. This is what can actually solve my issue. all this time I was looking for the unique id that was being generated, now I realize that I can also generate the same. Thank you once again.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion and also the link to the faker

Comment: No problem, I've been in the same boat a few times :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the new gmail api directly. you will need a manual oauth flow to get the token, then use urlFetch to make the call.
 https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send

 it returns a message resource with its id. might also be possible to do this with advanced services but i havent tried. i have done it with urlfetch and worked ok.

Comment: looks promising, let's see how can I use it, as my code is in Google script.

Comment: its possible to call from apps script, ive done it. see urlfetchApp

Answer (score 1):

Can you set the Message-Id header on the email?  (Not sure if the apps scripts allows that or overwrites it or not.)  If so, I'd generate a unique Id that way and you can look it up using a search "rfc822msgid:".

Comment: The api seems to be very restricted to limited options see [GmailApp.sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String))

Answer (score 1):

create a draft first, then send it

```
function sendEmail(opts) {
  let draft = GmailApp.createDraft(recipient=opts.recipient, subject=opts.title, {
      htmlBody: opts.msg,
  });
  draft.send()
  let ret = {
    id: draft.getId(),
    messageId: draft.getMessageId(),
  }
  console.log('sendEmail results: ', ret )
  return ret
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## 2022 Update

`GmailDraft.send()` returns a `GmailMessage` you can use that to label the sent message.

Example:

```js
const draft = GmailApp.createDraft('Foo <foo@bar.com>','Lorem Ipsum','Dolor Sit Amet');
const label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Test');
const msg = draft.send();
const thrd = msg.getThread();
label.addToThread(thrd);
```

Answer (score 0):

[google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) solution working for sent messages with methods: `GmailApp`, `MailApp`

1. enable `Gmail` service
2. use the code:

---

```
  var messages = Gmail.Users.Messages.list(
    "me", {q: "subject:Test Me", maxResults: 1}
  ).messages;

  console.log(messages[0].id)
```